# Mangeto related products price issue on configurable product pages

Tags: magento, configurable

All the Prices, shown within a Price Box div on a Configurable product page or product with custom options (so the Related products, Featured product in menu, upsells etc.) all show ' **please select required fields**' or the price which is calculated for the configurable product itself.

Has anyone had this problem or know what it could be? Have been searching for an answer but cannot find anything that fixes it.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you would lie more info please let me know!

Comment: I think I have narrowed it down to a JavaScript problem, but wouldn't like to edit this as I believe this would mean editing the core?

Comment: The problem was custom JavaScript, by a third party developer. Which was updating the class price, which appears more than once on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was custom JavaScript, by a third party developer. Which was updating the class price, which appears more than once on the page.